# Obtener registros de ayer, mes pasado en claususa where en sql

Tags: mysql

tengo un campo tipo timestamp y quedría saber como obtener un filtro tipo where para la fecha de ayer, el mes pasado o año pasado. Trabajo en el backend con php y mySQL.

El formato del campo fecha es de este tipo: 2020-09-21 17:50:00
Y he estado intentando hacerlo con esta clausula para obtener los valores del año pasado pero no hay forma.

```
Select * from registros where YEAR(timestamp)=YEAR(-1);
```

Gracias

Comment: year trae el año, no el mes.. probaste con month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por ejemplo, para obtener el año actual usarias

```
year(Now())
```

donde [year](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/year.html) es la funcion que obtiene el año de una fecha y [now](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) es la funcion que obtiene la fecha actual.

Ahora, si queres el año anterior, podrias hacer

```
year(dateadd(now(),interval -1 year))
```

donde ademas de las funciones que ya vimos, tenemos [dateadd](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) que se utiliza para hacer calculos aritmeticos con fechas, y luego como parametro le pasamos el [intervalo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals) a sumar (o restar en este caso)

Lo mismo, se puede hacer con las funciones month o cualquier otra que utilice fechas.

En este caso, tu where quedaria asi

```
YEAR(timestamp)=year(dateadd(now(),interval -1 year))
```