# Problema Mysql me arroja resultado en tabla NULL con la funcion DATE

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Hola amigos tengo un problema con mi código o con mi base de datos, trato de que me arroje el resultado en la tabla pero solo me aparece NULL.

Solo quiero que me arroje las tarjetas de crédito que expiran en 2017, pero no logro encontrarlo.

Este es mi código de la tabla:

```
create table tarjetacredito (
numtarjeta int not null,
tipotarj varchar (12),
idbanco int, 
nombrebanco varchar (12),
verif_tarjeta int,
venc_tarjeta date);
```

Y este otro para que me arroje los datos en la tabla.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal o que le hace falta a mi código?

```
select numtarjeta, tipotarj, venc_tarjeta, verif_tarjeta
from tarjetacredito
where venc_tarjeta like '17' ;
```

Hice lo que me dijo @Srsole y me sigue apareciendo igual, adjunto imagen.

### Se resolvió usando:

```
SELECT * FROM tarjetacredito WHERE DATE_FORMAT(venc_tarjeta, "%Y") = '2017'
```

Comment: Te falta mostrar el codigo de la consulta que estas haciendo. Ademas por que estas usando el operador like ?? como estas guardando la fecha de vencimiento ?

Comment: ` create table tarjetacredito (
numtarjeta int not null,
tipotarj varchar (12),
idbanco int, 
nombrebanco varchar (12),
verif_tarjeta int,
venc_tarjeta date); `  La estoy guardando con la funcion DATE. @Excorpion

Comment: si venc_tarjeta es una fecha, porque no sacas el año de esa fecha y lo comparas con 17 en lugar de hacer un like, que no funciona?

Comment: o pones el formato correcto, o haces un date y extraes el año, o haces un like %

Comment: @gbianchi no entiendo, como quedaria el codigo?

Comment: @Srsole ya lo hice un like % y me sigue arrojando el mismo resultado

Comment: esta no contesta tu duda? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/391154/324

Comment: Es que el like no te puede obtener el año de un date, a menos que lo conviertas o lo extraigas @JuanJesus

Comment: es lo que dice @JuanJesus, prueba asi: SELECT * FROM tarjetacredito WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(venc_tarjeta, "%Y") = '20107'

Comment: @Srsole ya he puesto el codigo como me indicas, pero me sigue arrojando en la tabla el problema

Comment: Y que problema da o que error te indica?, estaria bien que nos dieras unos datos de muestra

Comment: He añadido una imagen en la publicacion original

Comment: has puesto 20107, tiene algo que ver?

Comment: Leer el enlace que te pase y usar year no es una opcion?

Comment: Listo, tenias razon el problema fue que no me fije en el numero, Muchas gracias @Srsole

Comment: Pues ya esta solucionado. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EL problema es el campo, que al ser fecha no puedes tratarlo así.

Así es lo correcto:

```
SELECT * FROM tarjetacredito WHERE DATE_FORMAT(venc_tarjeta, "%Y") = '2017'
```

`DATE_FORMAT` coge, en este caso, el año y así si puedes compararlo.

Comment: Es más **preciso**: `WHERE DATE_FORMAT(venc_tarjeta, "%Y") = 2017`

Comment: Si lo dices por las comillas yo simpre las pongo por el principio basico de la prudencia

Comment: acabo de encontrarlo `DATE_FORMAT() returns a string` en https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format, por si quieres pegarle un ojo

Comment: no es mas simple usar la funcion year si es un datetime el campo? @A.Cedano

Comment: Toda la razón, me confundí con `YEAR()`, en cuyo caso sería: `... WHERE YEAR(venc_tarjeta) = 2017`

Comment: esta bien, pero si quiero poner solo '17', que era lo que el OP tenia, pues ya no te vale

Comment: @gbianchi con `YEAR()` al menos la consulta es más simple, en cuanto a rendimiento no sabría decirte, porque no tengo ninguna base documental ni prueba al respecto. Si se trata de comparar con el año formateado (últimos dos dígitos), Srsole, es evidente que habrá que usar `DATE_FORMAT()`